# Is the set of all vectors of the form $(a,b,c)$ where $ab=ac$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So, to prove that the set $W$, $W=\{(a,b,c)|ab=ac\}$ is a subspace, we have to prove that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

But how do I verify the condition in this case?

Comment: Hint: try some examples with vectors from $W$ to see if it is closed under those operations.

Comment: But this equation is only true when a=0 or when b and c are equal. Aren't b and c supposed to be different?

Comment: @Firdaws Exactly. So $(0,1,2)\in W$ and $(1,0,0)\in W$. What about their sum?

Comment: Not member of W ! So, b and c can be equal without problem when I try some examples?

Comment: Yes, they can be equal. $b$ can be whatever real number, $c$ can be whatever real number. They can happen to be equal.  Note $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ also will mean every vector whatsover, not only those where all coordinates are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short argument that it is not a subspace is given by 
$(0,1,2)$ is in the set $(1,1,1)$ is in the set, yet their sum is not.

How, could be think of this? Let us inspect: $ab = ac$. When it is true? 
If $a=0$, then it is true for any $b,c$. If $a$ is non-zero, then it's true when $b=c$.

Thus your set is the union of the set of vectors with $a=0$ (a plane) and the set with $b=c$ (another plane).

If we take a vector in the one and a vector in the other, the sum of the tw will usually be outside either of the two planes. (Draw a picture in 2D with lines instead of planes.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $W = \{(0,b,c); a,b \in R \} \cup \{(a,b,c) \in R^2; b=c \}$, therefore, how $A = \{(0,b,c); a,b \in R \}$ and $B =\{(a,b,c) \in R^2; b=c\}$ are subspace, $W$ is a subsapece if, only if, we have that $A \subset B$ or $B \subset A$, but those is not true.